# 'HttpPostedFileBase' has no key defined. Define the key for this EntityType

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

I have create an application to upload image in database
this is my model

```
[Table("ImageGallery")]
public class ImageGallery
{
    [Key]
    public int ImageID { get; set; }
    public int ImageSize { get; set; }
    public string FileName { get; set; }
    public byte[] ImageData { get; set; }
    [Required(ErrorMessage="Please select Image File")]
    public HttpPostedFileBase file { get; set; }
}
```

this is my database model

```
public class TPADB : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<ImageGallery> imagegallery { get; set; }
}
```

this is my view

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Upload", "ImageUP", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
{
@Html.ValidationSummary(true)
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>Select File : </td>
        <td>
            @Html.TextBoxFor(Model => Model.file, new { type="file"})
            @Html.ValidationMessage("CustomError")
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="submit" value="Upload" />
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

}

this is my controller

```
[HttpGet]
    public ActionResult Upload()
    {
        return View();
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Upload(ImageGallery IG)
    {
        IG.FileName = IG.file.FileName;
        //IG.ImageSize = IG.file.ContentLength;
        byte[] data = new byte[IG.file.ContentLength];
        IG.file.InputStream.Read(data, 0, IG.file.ContentLength);
        IG.ImageData = data;
        using (TPADB db = new TPADB())
        {
            db.imagegallery.Add(IG);
            db.SaveChanges();
        }
        return View();
    }
```

but it throughs an error that 
"One or more validation errors were detected during model generation:

TPA.Models.HttpPostedFileBase: : EntityType 'HttpPostedFileBase' has no key defined. Define the key for this EntityType.
HttpPostedFileBases: EntityType: EntitySet 'HttpPostedFileBases' is based on type 'HttpPostedFileBase' that has no keys defined."

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out, make the following changes to the model:

```
public partial class ImageGallery
    {
        [Key]
        public int ImageID { get; set; }
        public int ImageSize { get; set; }
        public string FileName { get; set; }
        public byte[] ImageData { get; set; }
        public string File 
        {
            get
            {
                string mimeType = "image/png";
                string base64 = Convert.ToBase64String(ImageData);
                return string.Format("data:{0},{1}", mimeType, base64);
            }
        }

    }
```

Then add this line to the controller:

```
         HttpPostedFileBase File = Request.Files[0];
```

Replace any IG.File entry with File for example:

```
         if (File.ContentLength > (2 * 1024 * 1024))
```