# 'HttpPostedFileBase' has no key defined

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, ef-code-first

I have a web application to upload image to database and to retreive them.

```
public class ImageGallery
{
    [Key]
    public int ImageID { get; set; }
    public int ImageSize { get; set; }
    public string FileName { get; set; }
    public byte[] ImageData { get; set; }
    [Required(ErrorMessage="Please select Image File")]
    public HttpPostedFileBase file { get; set; }
}
```

and my database context class is something like this

```
public class MyDatabaseEntities : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<ImageGallery> ImageGalleries { get; set; }
}
```

and here is my controller

```
public ActionResult Upload()
{
    return View();
}
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Upload(ImageGallery IG)
{
    IG.FileName = IG.File.FileName;
    IG.ImageSize = IG.File.ContentLength;
    byte[] data = new byte[IG.File.ContentLength];
    IG.File.InputStream.Read(data, 0, IG.File.ContentLength);
    IG.ImageData = data;
    using(MyDatabaseEntities dc = new MyDatabaseEntities())
    {
        dc.ImageGalleries.Add(IG);
        dc.SaveChanges();
    }
    return RedirectToAction("Gallery");
}
```

now when i try to upload the image it giving me following error

> EntityType 'HttpPostedFileBase' has no key defined. Define the key for this EntityType. HttpPostedFileBases: EntityType: EntitySet 'HttpPostedFileBases' is based on type 'HttpPostedFileBase' that has no keys defined.

I have seen one of question on stack overflow-----['HttpPostedFileBase' has no key defined. Define the key for this EntityType](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28735336/httppostedfilebase-has-no-key-defined-define-the-key-for-this-entitytype). I tried the solution but did not get any success.

I was following this blog for this purpose------
http://dotnetawesome.com/mvc/how-to-upload-image-to-database-and-show-in-view-without-image-handler

Comment: You cant store a `HttpPostedFileBase` in a database. Remove it from your data model and use a view model that includes that property.

Comment: @StephenMuecke then i will have to make many changes.Is it possible to make some changes only in data model and controller to make it working

Comment: Do you need display/edit any properties of `ImageGallery` in the view? If not then simply use `public ActionResult Upload(HttpPostedFileBase file)` and in the view `<input type="file" name="file" />` (and remove the property from your data model)

Comment: Its not still making full sense....If i remove the property and then tried like this------ public ActionResult Upload(ImageGallery IG, HttpPostedFileBase file)
        {      file.FileName = IG.FileName;                                                            here i am unable to set file name and content lenght property to save into db. am not getting sense here. PLzzz see the code

Comment: No, Remove the `ImageGallery IG` parameter. In the first line of the method, initialize a new instance of `ImageGallery` and set its properties based on the `file` values

Comment: okkk okkk let me try

Comment: public ActionResult Upload(HttpPostedFileBase file)
        {
            ImageGallery IG = new ImageGallery();
            file.FileName = IG.FileName;                                  exceptions-System.NotImplementedException                     property or indexer System.web.HttpPostedFileBase.FileName' cannot be assigned to --- it is readonly

Comment: Other way around :) - `IG.FileName = file.FileName;`

Comment: okk got it Sorry for silly mistake

Comment: @using (Html.BeginForm("Upload", "ImageGallery", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
{
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>Select File : </td>
            <td>
                @Html.TextBoxFor(Model => Model.File, new { type = "file" })
                @Html.ValidationMessage("CustomError")
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="submit" value="Upload" />
            </td>            what to pass here ???

Comment: You don't need a model - just `<input type="file" name="file" />` as I indicated above if all the form is doing is uploading a file.

Comment: yipeeee !! its working thanks @StephenMuecke but am unable to mark ur cmnt as answer for other users :-(

Comment: Depending on individual requirements I think it is also prudent to note that you can create fields that aren't mapped in Entity Framework using the [NotMapped Attribute](http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/notmapped-dataannotations-attribute-in-code-first.aspx).  This would have prevented EF from trying to store that field and therefore would have prevented the error messages.  The rest of the code (at first glance) would have worked without change.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Simply try a new view model with properties like this-----

```
    public class ImageViewModel
   {
    public int ImageID { get; set; }
    public int ImageSize { get; set; }
    public string FileName { get; set; }
    public byte[] ImageData { get; set; }
    public HttpPostedFileBase File { get; set; }
   }
```

and change your controller like this-----

```
    public ActionResult Upload(HttpPostedFileBase file)
    {
        ImageGallery IG = new ImageGallery();
    IG.FileName = file.FileName;
      IG.ImageSize = file.ContentLength;

        byte[] data = new byte[file.ContentLength];
        file.InputStream.Read(data, 0, file.ContentLength);

           IG.ImageData = data;

        var model = new ImageViewModel
        {
            FileName = file.FileName,
            ImageSize = file.ContentLength,
            ImageData = data,
            File = file
        };


        using(MyDatabaseEntities dc = new MyDatabaseEntities())
        {
            dc.ImageGalleries.Add(IG);
            dc.SaveChanges();
        }
        return View(model);

    }

}
```

}

and change your view page like this------

```
    @model Image.Models.ImageViewModel

<h2>Upload</h2>
 @using (Html.BeginForm("Upload", "ImageGallery", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
 {
  @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
  <table>
    <tr>
        <td>Select File : </td>
        <td>
            @Html.TextBoxFor(Model => Model.File, new { type = "file" })
            @Html.ValidationMessage("CustomError")
        </td>
       <td>
            <input type="submit" value="Upload" />
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
 }
```

Answer (score 4):

Try this

```
[NotMapped]
public HttpPostedFileBase File { get; set; }
```

This will not map to the database.

The error occurs because their is no datatype `HttpPostedFileBase` in your table

Answer (score 1):

You cannot store `HttpPostedFileBase` in a database field (its a complex object containing multiple properties). You could exclude this using the `[NotMapped]` attribute, however your model and your view really have no relationship (your not including any inputs for the other properties of your model).

Instead your view can be just

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Upload", "ImageGallery", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
{
    <input type="file" name="file" />
    <input type = "submit" value="Upload" />
}
```

and change the POST method to

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Upload(HttpPostedFileBase file)
{
    if (file.ContentLength > 0) // check a file was selected
    {
       // Initialize a new instance of the data model and set its properties
       ImageGallery model = new ImageGallery()
       {
           FileName = file.FileName,
           ImageSize = file.ContentLength,
           ....
       };
       .... // save and redirect
    }
    else {
      // add a model state error and return the view?
    }
}
```

Comment: You ask me to add an answer, which i have done and the you accept another (which just plagiarizes mine). Good luck getting any help in the future.